# Mac OSX Google Magenta Bazael Test Fails

Tags: macos, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow, bazel, magenta

I have been trying to follow the instructions in the ReadMe.md and each time the tests have failed.

From the Command Line:

```
 bazel test //magenta/...
 .....
 WARNING: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/external/protobuf/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/external/protobuf/WORKSPACE (@__main__) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf); this will cause a build error in future versions.
 INFO: Found 30 targets and 5 test targets...
 FAIL: //magenta/lib:melodies_lib_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/melodies_lib_test/test.log).
 FAIL: //magenta/lib:note_sequence_io_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/note_sequence_io_test/test.log).
 FAIL: //magenta/scripts:convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/scripts/convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences_test/test.log).
 FAIL: //magenta/lib:midi_io_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/midi_io_test/test.log).
 FAIL: //magenta/lib:sequence_to_melodies_test (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/sequence_to_melodies_test/test.log).
 INFO: Elapsed time: 57.036s, Critical Path: 38.75s
 //magenta/lib:melodies_lib_test                                          FAILED in 24.3s
   /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/melodies_lib_test/test.log
 //magenta/lib:midi_io_test                                               FAILED in 1.2s
   /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/midi_io_test/test.log
 //magenta/lib:note_sequence_io_test                                      FAILED in 24.2s
   /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/note_sequence_io_test/test.log
 //magenta/lib:sequence_to_melodies_test                                  FAILED in 6.4s
   /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/lib/sequence_to_melodies_test/test.log

 //magenta/scripts:convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences_test                FAILED in 24.2s
   /private/var/tmp/_bazel_KaitlynChait/196a379e499c76d9a4585793a4982323/execroot/magenta/bazel-out/local-opt/testlogs/magenta/scripts/convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences_test/test.log

 Executed 5 out of 5 tests: 5 fail locally.
```

Answer (score 0):

Including some of the logs listed in the failure messages will help track things down for sure, but this may be related to this bug report: https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/issues/95